# My website is accessible to some users but throws "this site can't be reached" for others

Tags: dns, hosting, web-hosting

I recently set up a website http://shehara.co and it works fine on my pc and phone and some of my friends, when working properly it should display "nothing to see here" on the top left corner, But for most users, it does not load.

I tried pinging it through my command prompt and that fails too(all packets lost), then I tried the site downforeveryoneorjustme.com which again tells the site is down, I'm confused to as what is happening, I'm using a free host service called byet.host, can someone explain how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Now site is working but showing nothing is here I think at that time server has got to many requests that's why it cannot be reached .

Comment: well I still can't ping it from my command prompt, still throws request timed out